# spark-submit throws: ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark

I am attempting to submit an app to my remote Spark 2.3.2 cluster (which I am able to access from my client machine). I keep getting `ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext. java.lang.NullPointerException` and I just don't understand why. I have been able to run this code locally and it works.

Any insights or pointers as to what `ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext. java.lang.NullPointerException` might mean would be appreciated

```
spark-submit --class com.mycode.example.Counter --master spark://my-remote-spark-master:7077 ./target/scala-2.11/example-hcl-spark-scala-mycodeblock.jar /users/mycode/input /users/mycode/output

...
2018-11-14 15:15:11 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.registerBlockManager(BlockManagerMaster.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.initialize(BlockManager.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at com.mycode.example.Counter$.main(Counter.scala:27)
    at com.mycode.example.Counter.main(Counter.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-11-14 15:15:11 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2018-11-14 15:15:11 INFO  SparkContext:54 - SparkContext already stopped.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.registerBlockManager(BlockManagerMaster.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.initialize(BlockManager.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at com.mycode.example.Counter$.main(Counter.scala:27)
    at com.mycode.example.Counter.main(Counter.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)2018-11-14 15:15:11 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-11-14 15:15:11 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-11-14 15:15:11 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /private/var/folders/0q/8hp24_5n78q2np59_lpm10fh0000gn/T/spark-91cc1f38-cb03-489f-90cb-2d65763dc0b9
2018-11-14 15:15:11 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /private/var/folders/0q/8hp24_5n78q2np59_lpm10fh0000gn/T/spark-720b55a1-4723-42ac-87d4-befc06b0f2e4
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was resolved by creating HDFS/MapR-FS home directory for the user.